# return statement in synchronized in android does?

Tags: android, synchronization, synchronized

```
void fun() {
    // some code
    synchronized (this) {
        if(condition) {
            return;
        }
        // some code
    }
    // some code
}
```

Does this `return` call return from method `fun` or just out of the `synchronized` block?

Comment: see the closing brace of synchronized block.you will get the answer. :p

Comment: Return always exits method. Try to put something after the return statement (without if) in the synchronized block and it won't even compile because of unreachable statement.

Comment: its a huge code i cant get even if i put log :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return will exit your function. A call of return always exits a function. Except a try finally where the finally block will executed before exiting your function.

Comment: Also note that in this case : yes, the return statement will end the method bit it will also release the locks acquired in the synchronized block.

Answer (score 3):

`return` inside a `synchronized` block will first release the monitor held  (`this` in your example) and then exit the method.

Answer (score 1):

1. It returns from function fun() only, any block doesn't have any return statement.for loop block you can have break but not return.
2. Also the block has no return type so how can you return from there, so only you can return value from function as it has return type.